# Why is this snippet involving a static lambda in a class a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I ran into this snippet of code recently. Valgrind says that there's a memory leak, but I have no idea why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
 
class Player {
public:
    Player() {
        static auto foo = [this]() {
            nums_.insert(0);
        };
        foo();
    }
private:
    std::set<int> nums_;
};
 
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Player>> players;
    players.insert({"eenz", std::make_shared<Player>()});
    players.erase("eenz");
    players.insert({"eenz", std::make_shared<Player>()});
}
```

When I remove `static` from the lambda, the memory leak goes away. I tried to reason out why this was a memory leak, but I had no luck. Would anyone know the reason why this is a memory leak?

Comment: Valgrind only tells you that memory has been allocated but not freed, that doesn't necessarily mean it's been leaked, just not deleted yet

Comment: Your lambda will however always operate on the first object you create which is probably not what you want especially if that first object ever gets deleted

Comment: I thought that the lambda only operated on the first object we create, but I was a little confused because of this snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/5eGv9x, which behaves like the lambda operates on all objects created.

Comment: I don't think that snippet behaves as if the lambda operates on each object. In fact, if you print out the size of `nums_` for each `Player` object, I think you'll see that for the first it has size 4 while for the rest it has size 0. In any case, that snippet seems a bit dubious to me. It's not entirely clear to me what it's trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Ahh, got it, thank you!!